# Getting error while running the script in Webdriver: An error has occurred in the script on this page line 27

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the error when running the following script in Webdriver. 
Error Message: An error has occurred in the script on this page line 27

```
package Example;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class Script {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.700creditsolution.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Set<String> windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> iter= windowids.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("Main Window ID :"+iter.next());
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).sendKeys("skumara4");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).sendKeys("Test1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_LoginButton")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000L);

        windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
        iter= windowids.iterator();
        String main_windowID=iter.next();
        String tabbed_windowID=iter.next();
        System.out.println("Popup Window ID :"+main_windowID);
        //switch over to pop-up window
        driver.switchTo().window(tabbed_windowID);
        System.out.println("Pop-up window Title : "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BtnClose']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.switchTo().window(main_windowID);
        String msg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")).getText();
        System.out.println(msg);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Getting Error after the popup window title is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on copy pasting your code, I get your line 27 to be

```
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

The reason an error is shown is because there is an additional "`L`"

What you probably wanted was

```
Thread.sleep(5000); # A 5 second wait
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason you have pointed out is not correct. it is giving error at          "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BtnClose']")).click();"     line, not at the line 27 in the script.